# Keep customized colors with geom_polygon()

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, polygon

I have plotted a map of France with customized colors with `map()` :

```
map(database="france", fill=TRUE, col=color)
```

Results :

[image: map of france with the colors]

(don't mind the two errors)

and then I want to put this map with a projection of Lambert using `ggplot2` package :

```
head(fortify(carte_france))
ggplot(map('france'), aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(col = 1) + 
  coord_map(projection = "lambert", parameters = c(lat0 = 41.366005 , lat1 = 51.097523))
```

However it gives me this :

[image: map of france with geom_polygon()]

I know that the dark colours comes from the arg `fill` from `geom_polygon()` but is there a way to tell the function `geom_polygon()` to not use the arg `fill` or to keep the colors I have put before ?

Vector of colours, `color` :

```
c("yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", 
"gold1", "sienna3", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "sienna3", 
"gold1", "gold1", "gold1", "sienna3", "sienna3", "gold1", "dodgerblue2", 
"dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "gold1", "dodgerblue2", "sienna3", 
"dodgerblue2", "burlywood2", "dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", 
"dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", "dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", 
"palevioletred4", "gold1", "palevioletred4", "gold1", "darkorchid4", 
"gold1", "darkorchid4", "palevioletred4", "green4", "cyan4", 
"gold1", "palevioletred4", "burlywood2", "green4", "green4", 
"cyan4", "darkorchid4", "green4", "burlywood2", "palevioletred4", 
"burlywood2", "green4", "green4", "palevioletred4", "palevioletred4", 
"palevioletred4", "green4", "burlywood2", "olivedrab2", "green4", 
"olivedrab2", "darkorchid4", "darkorchid4", "cyan4", "darkorchid4", 
"cyan4", "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", 
"cyan4", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", 
"cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", "cyan4", 
"cyan4", "cyan4", "orange2", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
"olivedrab2", "orange2", "olivedrab2", "orangered1", "orange2", 
"orangered1", "orange2", "orange2", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
"orangered1", "orange2", "orangered1", "orange2", "orangered1", 
"olivedrab2", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
"orange2", "orange2", "orange2", "chartreuse3", "orangered1", 
"chartreuse3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `map_data` that create a dataset in the good format for ggplot with maps from library map. In which case, you will not have these white dots on your map.
As you defined the order of your colors based on the order of polygons in the `map` function, I created a table for left joining with `map_data`.

```
# Get polygon order from map
map_france <- map(database="france", fill=TRUE)

# Create a dataframe with department and corresponding colors
names_col <- data.frame(
  region = map_france$names,
  col_dpt = c("yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", 
              "gold1", "sienna3", "yellowgreen", "yellowgreen", "sienna3", 
              "gold1", "gold1", "gold1", "sienna3", "sienna3", "gold1", "dodgerblue2", 
              "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "gold1", "dodgerblue2", "sienna3", 
              "dodgerblue2", "burlywood2", "dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", 
              "dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", "dodgerblue2", "palevioletred4", 
              "palevioletred4", "gold1", "palevioletred4", "gold1", "darkorchid4", 
              "gold1", "darkorchid4", "palevioletred4", "green4", "cyan4", 
              "gold1", "palevioletred4", "burlywood2", "green4", "green4", 
              "cyan4", "darkorchid4", "green4", "burlywood2", "palevioletred4", 
              "burlywood2", "green4", "green4", "palevioletred4", "palevioletred4", 
              "palevioletred4", "green4", "burlywood2", "olivedrab2", "green4", 
              "olivedrab2", "darkorchid4", "darkorchid4", "cyan4", "darkorchid4", 
              "cyan4", "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", 
              "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", 
              "cyan4", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab2", "cyan4", "cyan4", 
              "cyan4", "cyan4", "orange2", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
              "olivedrab2", "orange2", "olivedrab2", "orangered1", "orange2", 
              "orangered1", "orange2", "orange2", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
              "orangered1", "orange2", "orangered1", "orange2", "orangered1", 
              "olivedrab2", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", "orangered1", 
              "orange2", "orange2", "orange2", "chartreuse3", "orangered1", 
              "chartreuse3")
)
```

Then you can join this dataframe to data created by `map_data` and call the colour vector with ggplot.

```
# Get the map in the correct format for ggplot
# And join the correspondance of colors
carte_france <- map_data('france') %>%
  left_join(names_col)

# Plot
ggplot(carte_france, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(col = 1, fill = carte_france$col_dpt) + 
  coord_map(projection = "lambert", 
            parameters = c(lat0 = 41.366005 , lat1 = 51.097523))
```

For your information, on the website of the IGN (http://professionnels.ign.fr/geofla), you can download map of French departements, with the information on the region. In this case, it would be easier to create a vector of colors based on the region name...

Comment: Yeah I have found the answer 10 minutes ago and I did the same but the problem with IGN is that they only give the centroids for the departments and thus I can't geolocate my points for which I have only the latitude and longitude since the coords used to plot are not the same.

Comment: You can reproject the IGN shapefile or your points using `sp::spTransform`. But this is subject different that this question...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will check if it's possible to get the projection by longitude and latitude with this function.